# Check Apache server for It Works

Tags: apache2

I'm logged in to my VPS through an SSH tunnel and have Apache installed on the server. Apache appears healthy and running.

```
sudo systemctl status apache2

● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-02-08 20:20:51 UTC; 1 day 16h ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 34352 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
       ├─20407 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
       ├─34370 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
       └─34371 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

I'd like to do a simple test in the shell in order to visibly see the `It Works!` default message.

I run 
    `/var/www/html$ http://6.5.4.2`

only receive:

```
-bash: http://6.5.4.2: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use a command to connect to your URL like `curl`. Just entering the URL in bash does not work.

```
curl http://6.5.4.2
```

That should print the HTML in your terminal. If you want to interpret the HTML code you could use `lynx` which is a text-based web browser for shell.

```
lynx http://6.5.4.2
```